# how to print SQL statement in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

As you know, we can use the method `DB::getQueryLog()` to print the sql statement in Laravel 4.

But it doesn't work in Laravel 5.

Comment: you need to `DB::enableQueryLog();` in advance

Comment: is this for debugging purpose ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query log is [disabled by default](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/e0abfe5c49d225567cb4dfd56df9ef05cc297448) in L5. Call

```
DB::connection()->enableQueryLog();
$queries = DB::getQueryLog();
```

before trying to log it. See the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/database#query-logging) for more info
.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to see the currently running SQL query you can use this

https://github.com/itsgoingd/clockwork

installation instructions are clearly mentioned in the README file

[image]